# URL Rewrite for one level?

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I need a rewrite rule that uses only one parameter.

```
<rewrite url="~/(.+).aspx to="www.mysite.com/results?search=$1" />
```

The issue with this is that I now cannot access my default.aspx page, and basically all requests that are one file deep - images, stylesheets, etc.

I'm guessing there are some exception rules that can be written?

Also, can I on-the-fly do character replacing such as replacing spaces with "+", underscores with dashes, etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not about a rule, you need to configure iis to process with asp.net all file requests.

here you are step by step.

> > > http://forums.iis.net/t/1015329.aspx